# Login failed for user ''. - ASP.NET MVC FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My "Register" page used to work, until I started using FormsAuthentication and FormsAuthenticationTicket to login.

Now on Register, it fails when checking if an email already exists in the database, on this line

```
if (Global.DC.Users.Where(x=>x.Email == Email).Count() > 0)
  return "The email address already exists in the database";
```

with this error message

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Login failed for user ''.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the SQL login is invalid.  I would check your connection string to see if that has changed, and if not, I would validate that the SQL Login and Database User is configured correctly.

Typically you may not realise this has happened if you are changing how your DataContext is being called, if you used to explicitly test it using a specific connection string, or create it with the default constructor (`new ....DataContext()`). Using the default constructor normally uses the design time connection string configured in the `Settings.settings` project item which stores the connection string name to reference in your `web.config` configuration file.  Are you still calling it the same way?

On another note, I noticed you're calling your `DataContext` through your `Global` class.  This is generally considered a bad design, and you should really consider using a unit-of-work` approach to data access, e.g., instantiate and release your context after you're finished with it:

```
using (var context = new DataContext()) {
    // Do work here.
}
```

And another quick one, its more efficient to using `Any` instead of `Count` as using `Count` causes the entire enumerable to be enumerated to get the result, where as `Any` will fall out at the first valid instance.

Comment: You're right it was the connection string! Thanks a lot for that and your advices! :)